# How can i read text from an image using tesseract. I can't find the good options

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Having some issues finding the right option to read a text from an image using tesseract and convert.exe 
Any help or suggest will be very helpful

Comment: example of image https://www.bea-brak.de/bravsearch/jcaptcha?pfdrid_c=false&uid=9084cd68-7d9f-486b-9971-44e7c7c04b41

Comment: What are the issues and what options are you considering? And how are you using convert.exe?